# how to import data from excel sheet and provide that data to navigate to the website

Tags: excel, webdriver

I need to import data from Excel sheet and provide it to navigate to the website.Can you'll suggest me how to achieve it with selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

> Here you need to use apache POI library. [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/download.html)

```
Hope this will help you

  String      fileName1 = "D://TestData//MyDataSheet1.xlsx",
  FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName1));
      XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook (fis1);
      XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
      Iterator ite1 = sheet1.rowIterator(); 

    while(ite1.hasNext()){
        Row row = (Row) ite1.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();
        while(cite.hasNext()){
            Cell a1 = cite.next(),
                 a2 = cite.next();

              driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress")).clear();
              driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress")).sendKeys(a1.toString().trim());
              driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
              driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(a2.toString().trim());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tel me how it'l take data and navigate to the website                               like  [driver.navigate().to("imported url from excel sheet");]  I need to know the code,how it will exact the data and provide in the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

I use JXL api to extract data from excel. You can use either JXL or POI, which ever you waht. Below is the code to extract data:

```
String FilePath = "path to your excel file";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (FilePath);
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheetname");

String URL = sheet.getCell(row,col).getContents();

You can now use the above string URL in your code.

driver.navigate.To(URL) or

driver.get(URL);

I hope this helps.
```

Comment: i tried using same                                                                                 String URL = sh.getRow(25).getCell(10).getStringCellValue();                                          i am getting null pointer exception,its not navigating to the path.

Comment: If the URL is at row 25 and col 10 in your excel sheet, then you need to use:                                                                                                            String URL = sheet.getCell(10,25).getContents();                                      This should work for you

Comment: its giving me error saying "The method getCell(int, int) is undefined for the type Sheet"

Comment: Thats because the code i gave you works with JXl api and you are probably using apache poi. You need to download JXL jar to use JXL.                                 Below is the code for Apache poi:                                  String Filepath = "path to excel";
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Filepath);
  
  HSSFWorkbook hw = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        
  HSSFSheet sheet = hw.getSheet("sheet name");
  HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);                                          This cell value will now have the value of your URL from the excel sheet.

Comment: WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();driver.manage().window().maximize();
String Filepath = "C:/Documents and Settings/saalam/Desktop/Excel sheets/dyaworkbook1.xls";FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Filepath); HSSFWorkbook hw = new HSSFWorkbook(file);HSSFSheet sheet = hw.getSheet("sheet1"); 
String url = sheet.getRow(25).getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.navigate().to(url); i have used ur code like this but stil its giving me null pointer exception

Comment: You are getting NPE coz there is no data in your row(25) and col (10). Remember that in array, count starts from 0 and not 1. So, if the row number is 25 then probably you need to enter 24 and same for col, it should be 9. Hope this helps. I checked and the code is working fine for me.